# How is Exception handling implemented by programming languages?

Tags: exception, compiler-construction

I wanted to gain in-depth understanding of how programming languages implements exception handling and how exactly it works inside the hood. I have try to phrase this in many sub-questions as below.

1. What is the mechanism used by programing languages to implement try 
   { } catch { } blocks (under the hood)?
2. How exactly stack unwinding works inside?
3. What are the key differences between try { } / catch {} implementations between different languages like C++ and Java? Do they offer differ significantly or are they same?
4. Is setjump/longjump method of stack rewinding in C is similar to try/throw/catch block?
5. Why do people say that "stack unwinding" is costly?
6. What exactly is SEH (Structured Exception Handling?)

Comment: That's a lot of questions - including a few rather broad ones - at once. It may be wise to split those up and present what you've already gathered (you did do your own research, didn't you?).

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice description of how exception handling works, https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/26600/PBE2-Exceptions-2010-03-02.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately that link is now dead (death by `403`). Nevertheless _webarchive_ knows its stuff: https://web.archive.org/web/20110827072934/https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/26600/PBE2-Exceptions-2010-03-02.pdf